# When he married, he {could / was able to} go to Europe

Tags: modal-verbs

I'm not a native-speaker, so sometimes modal verbs are tricky for me.

Could is a modal verb that expresses general ability in the past tense.
'Was able to' is not a modal verb, and we can use 'was able to' to talk about an ability related to a single event or incident in the past.

So, I think like this:

He was rich. He could go to Europe.

In this case, he was rich, so, I don't know he actually had been to Europe or not, but he could go to Europe whenever he wanted to, because he was rich then. Am I thinking it right?

How about this:

He was rich, so when he married, he {could/was able to} go to Europe.

In this case 'could' or 'was able to'? 'When he married' is a single event, so, is 'was able to' right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're asking about grammar precision versus the overall sense. That said, I think all your examples are acceptable, but the way you use the phrasing comes with different shades of implication:

> He was rich. He could go to Europe.

This construction has a nice literary flair to it and tells me that he both was able to and probably did go to Europe (although as you suggest, it doesn't really say that; if you want a pure sense of that ability alone you might need to be more explicit: "He was rich. Rich enough to go to Europe if he liked.")

> He was rich, so when he married, he was able to go to Europe.

This is the clearest statement to my ears of what I think you're getting at. There's a direct causality here between being rich, marrying, and going to Europe as a result of both of those things.

> He was rich, so when he married, he could go to Europe.

This also sounds OK to me but because it says "he" and not e.g. "they" I'm left a bit confused about whether he went there on a honeymoon trip, or whether the marriage somehow fulfilled another condition to enable an ability to go, or something else.